# How can I implement a typeOf function?

Tags: function, types, idris, first-class

Since types are first-class in Idris, it seems like I should be able to write a `typeOf` function that returns the type of its argument:

```
typeOf : a => a -> Type
typeOf x = a
```

However, when I attempt to call this function, I get what looks like an error:

```
*example> typeOf 42
Can't find implementation for Integer
```

**How can I properly implement this `typeOf` function?** Or is there something more subtle about the idea of "getting the type of a value" that I'm missing, which would prevent the existence of such a function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write it this way:

```
typeOf : {a : Type} -> a -> Type
typeOf {a} _ = a
```

`a => b` is a function which has an implicit argument filled in by interface resolution. `{a : b} -> c` is a function with an implicit argument filled in by unification.

There is no need to refer to interfaces here. Every term has a single type. If you write `typeOf 42`, the implicit `a` is inferred to `Integer` by unification.

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed that part of the [documentation](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/miscellany.html#implicit-arguments).

Comment: Couldn't it just more simply be written as `typeOf : (a : b) -> Type;
typeOf _ = b`